# Change ssh identity for a given host

Tags: ssh

So I've installed CYGWIN on both machines.

If I do this it works:

```
ssh -i desktop_rsa root@remoteserver
```

This requires me to type in a password

```
ssh root@remoteserver
```

How do I change the default identity for ssh, so it picks up the right one?

I tried editing my known_hosts file looks something like this, with the identity at the end:

```
remote_server_ip ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2Esome_big_public_key_here0Dk44YdG///bz desktop_rsa
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your .ssh/config file by adding this:

```
Host remoteserver
IdentityFile desktop_rsa
```

Edit where remote server is your server you are connecting to and desktop_rsa is the path to your identity file.  You can get more info on this with

```
man ssh_config
```

Or just google for ssh config.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  To note, there are two files, /etc/ssh_config and /etc/sshd_config.  The one you need to edit is ssh_config

Comment: @JohnZ, yes, you can do this in `/etc/ssh_config` if you want the change to be system wide.  You can also do this in your own `~/.ssh/config` file if you want the changes to only effect your own user sessions.